# extending Module trough ApplicationRecord Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to extend a module in the application_record.rb file in Rails 5.0.

The module is located in the /lib folder:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  extend UpdateLive
  extend UpdatePre
end
```

When trying to use a method in one of the Models I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord::UpdateLive
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong, or if I forgot a step?

Comment: is there any module with name UpdateLive ? ?

Comment: I think it should be inside `models/` directory

Comment: Yes there is a module with filename update_live.rb with the name UpdateLive in the lib folder. I am pretty sure I put my modules there in the past without problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require update_live in your ApplicationRecord

`require 'update_live'`

or put `lib` folder in the autoload path.
In `application.rb`:

`config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

Comment: Although I added something similar config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) in a different project, this does not seem to work this time for whatever reason. Requiring fixed the problem. Thanks